# Python PyQt5 signals & slots

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, pyqt4, pyqt5

I am having some trouble applying the new pyqt5 [signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) into a script thats purpose is to test/invoke another problem I've been trying to solve, GUI freezing/crashing ... the aim is so that once these signals and slots are functioning correctly the GUI will not crash after +/- 30 seconds of runtime, and just continue on counting numbers until the end of time. I have provided a pyqt4 example although it would be great to have a pyqt5 solution. Thanks :)

```
from time import sleep
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
import random
import os
import time


class Cr(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):

        while True:
            rndInt = random.randint(1, 100000)
            timesleep = random.random()
            time.sleep(timesleep)
            for i in range(120):
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('host_UP'), 'foo' + str(rndInt), i)
                QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()


class Main_Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args): 
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.relativePath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

        self.Main_Window = uic.loadUi("Main_Window.ui", self)
        self.Main_Window.show()
        self.Main_Window.move(790, 300)

        self.GU = []
        ProgressThreads = self.printThreads
        self.details_label = []
        for i in range(120):
            self.details_label.insert(i, 0)
            self.details_label[i] = QLabel(" ")
            ProgressThreads.addWidget(self.details_label[i])
            ProgressThreads.addSpacing(6)
            self.details_label[i].setText(Tools.Trim.Short('Idle', 7))
            self.GU.insert(i, Cr())
            self.GU[i].start()

        self.connect(self.GU, QtCore.SIGNAL("host_UP"), self.UpdateHost)


    def UpdateHost(self, str1, pos1):
        self.details_label[pos1].setText(str1)


class guiUpdate():
    def GUI_main(self):
        self.GUI = GUI



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    guiUpdate.GUI_main.GUI = Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you for the help :)

**UPDATE**
The script below is a hopefully correct PyQt5 version of the script above. However the issue of crashing and 'not responding' message is still unresolved

```
from time import sleep
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
import random
import os
import time
import Tools
import sys


class Cr(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, sam):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.sam = sam

    def run(self):

        while True:
            rndInt = random.randint(1, 100000)
            timesleep = random.random()
            time.sleep(timesleep)
            for i in range(5):
                #time.sleep(1)

                self.sam.connect_and_emit_trigger('foo' + str(rndInt), i)
                #self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('host_UP'), 'foo' + str(rndInt), i)
                #QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()


class Main_Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args): 
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.relativePath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

        self.Main_Window = uic.loadUi("Main_Window.ui", self)
        self.Main_Window.show()
        self.Main_Window.move(790, 300)

        sam = Foo()


        self.GU = []
        ProgressThreads = self.ProgressThreads
        self.details_label = []
        for i in range(5):
            self.details_label.insert(i, 0)
            self.details_label[i] = QLabel(" ")
            ProgressThreads.addWidget(self.details_label[i])
            ProgressThreads.addSpacing(6)
            self.details_label[i].setText(Tools.Trim.Short('Idle', 7))
            self.GU.insert(i, Cr(sam))
            self.GU[i].start()


class Foo(QObject):
    # Define a new signal called 'trigger' that has no arguments.
    trigger = pyqtSignal()
    def connect_and_emit_trigger(self, str, i):
        self.str = str
        self.i = i

        self.trigger.connect(self.handle_trigger)
        self.trigger.emit()

    def handle_trigger(self):
        guiUpdate.GUI_main.GUI.details_label[self.i].setText(self.str)




class guiUpdate():
    def GUI_main(self):
        self.GUI = GUI



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    guiUpdate.GUI_main.GUI = Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: can you attach the Main_Window.ui file?

Answer (score 0):

The new recommended way to use threads (and the one I got the best results with) is to use `moveToThread()` instead of directly subclassing QThread. In short:

1. write a QObject subclass doing the actual work (let's call it QMyWorker). This will likely look a bit like your existing qthread subclass, with a `start()` or `run()` method etc.
2. create a parent-less instance of QMyWorker
3. create a parent-less instance of QThread
4. use `QMyWorker.moveToThread(your_thread_instance)` (I go by memory, double check the API in doc).
5. call your `QMyWorker.start()`

This approach worked for me for very long jobs (4GB files etc).

Answer (score 0):

I used  QThreadPool, QRunnable with a worker, can make more workers per thread.
Very good example with explanation here
https://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/multithreading-pyqt-applications-with-qthreadpool/

My PYQT5 was freezing up also, now i fine tune it with printing a TimeStamp